# Como subir multiples imagenes en laravel mediante un ciclo for?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Tengo un formulario para publicar artículos por secciones donde con un botón se van sumando secciones cada una con una imagen con el id del campo "url-img-1, url-img-2..." y ahora en el controller me gustaría subir todas con un for pero no me funciona el poner una variable en el request. Adjunto el código con comentarios:

```php
for($i=0, $i<20, $i++){
    $img = $request->file('url-img-'/*$i*/); //no se como concatenar la variable con el string, he probadob con + y con .
    if ($img != ''){
        $file_route = time().'.'.$img->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $img=Image::make($request->file('url-img-'/*$i*/))
            ->resize(1200, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                $constraint->upsize();})
            ->save('img/'.$file_route);
        $articulo->url-img-/*$i*/= $file_route;
    }
}
```

EDICION:
Codigo de blade:

```php
<input type="file" id="url-img-1" name="url-img-1" placeholder="imagen" />
<input type="file" id="url-img-2" name="url-img-2" placeholder="imagen" />
<input type="file" id="url-img-3" name="url-img-3" placeholder="imagen" />
<input type="file" id="url-img-4" name="url-img-4" placeholder="imagen" />
<input type="file" id="url-img-5" name="url-img-5" placeholder="imagen" />
<input type="file" id="url-img-6" name="url-img-6" placeholder="imagen" />
```

Codigo del controller:

```php
            for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
                $temp = 'url-img-' . $i;
                $img = $request->file($temp);
                if ($img != ''){
                    $file_route = time().$i.'.'.$img->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $img=Image::make($request->file($temp))
                            ->resize(1200, null, function ($constraint) {
                                $constraint->aspectRatio();
                                $constraint->upsize();})
                            ->save('img/'.$file_route);
                    $articulo->{'url_img_'.$i} = $file_route;
                }
            }
```

el código tal y como esta una imagen la sube da igual que sea la 1 o 2... si hay mas, da igual en que posición, no, solo sube la primera.

Comment: Y porque no solo haces name=`url-img[]`, seria mas sencillo y entendible

Comment: Como dice @Shassain Lo mas optimo es ponerles a todas de nombre `url-img[]` y luego solo recorrer `url-img` con un foreach en el controlador

Comment: De dónde sale la variable ´$articulo´? Es un modelo y la tabla tiene varios campos `url_img_x`? No veo que estés guardando el artículo, lo estás haciendo fuera del `for`?

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo a como agregar la variable `$i`:

Para concadenar la string usa un $var temporal `$temp = 'url-img-' . $i;` o con una cadena de tipo `"url-img-{$i}"`

y en la parte de `$articulo` prueba con `$articulo->{'url-img-' . $i}` o `$articulo[$temp]` si es un modelo

Comment: vale ahora si que funciona, pero ahora me surge otro problema, solo me sube la primera imagen y me guarda en la base de datos solo la primera.

Comment: vale,estoy haciendo pruebas y creo que es porque no le da tiempo a cargar todo entre un ciclo y otro. si subo la primera hace todo bien, si subo solo la segunda hace todo bien, pero si hago la primera y la segunda falla

Comment: @Superchicken no tengo suficiente info para responder si puedes subir el codigo de blade y el controlador para ver que esta pasando.

Comment: ya esta editado

Comment: @Superchicken Despues de hacer el ciclo si haces dd($article) que te sale?

Comment: el array rellenado pero solo se ha rellenado el hueco de la primera foto que he puesto osea no el hueco si no que el primer file, si el uno y el dos los he dejado sin foto y he puesto foto en el 3, 4, y 5 se sube y guarda en la base de datos el 3 y pasa del 4 y el 5.

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que primero leas el numero de archivos que estas enviando desde tu blade al controlador.

cuando tengas el resultado almacenado en una variable ya puedes armar el FOR

ejemplo:

`$num = $request->num;` /* con este voy a indicar cuantas veces voy a repetir  */
/* vamos a declarar 2 array para manejo de errores */
 `$msj_ok = array();` /* array para mensaje ok */ 
 `$msj_error = array();` /* array para mensaje error */

```
for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){


            if($request->hasFile('nombreInput'.$i)){
                $file = $request->file('nombreInput'.$i); 
                $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $size = $file->getSize();
                $pathBank = '\\BANCOS\\RECEPCION\\'. $name;

                if ($size > 0) {
                    $res = storage::disk('sftp')->put($pathBank,\File::get($file));
                    if ($res) {
                        array_push($msj_ok,'ok:'.$name);
                    }else{
                        array_push($msj_error,'error:'.$name);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Espero te sea de utilidad